# finding residues for poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm struggling to find the residues of the equation

$$
\frac{-z\ln(z)}{(z^2+a^2)(2-z)},
$$

with poles at $z=\pm ai$ and $z=2$.

I have the residue for $z=2$ as

$$
\frac{-2\ln2}{4+a^2}, 
$$

but I am struggling to find the residues for $\pm ai$.
Could anyone help me?

For $+ai$ I have
$$
\frac{-ai\ln(ai)}{2-ai},
$$

and for $-ai$, I have
$$
\frac{ai\ln(-ai)}{2+ai}
$$
but this doesn't give me the result I need.

Comment: which branch of $\log$ did u choose?

Comment: the branch is along the negative real axis, using a keyhole contour

Comment: ok, and which result do u expect?

Comment: Since $z^2+a^2=(z-a i)(z+a i)$ you are missing a term $2a i$ in the denominator for the residue at $a i$. Assuming $a i\ne \pm 2.$ Similarly, missing a term $-2a i$ in the residue at $-a i.$

Comment: yes that is exactly what i'm missing thank you!!!!!! :)

Comment: ................................................... trying to delete duplicate comment of mine!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with finding residues at $z=\pm i$ for this function is that the result depends on the branch cut chosen for the log.  For example, if you are using residues for evaluating an integral, the contour used in the contour integral will dictate the branch cut.  For example, if you were using a keyhole contour about the positive real axis, you would set $i=e^{i \pi/2}$ and $-i = e^{i 3 \pi/2}$.  In that case,

$$\log{(i a)} = \log{a} + i \frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$\log{(-i a)} = \log{a} + i \frac{3 \pi}{2}$$

On the other hand, if you are using a keyhole contour about the negative real axis, then you would set $-i= e^{-i \pi/2}$.